# Android ListView background problem with Activity Theme

Tags: android, listview, themes

I have a simple question here...
I've a simple ListView in my Activity, and in my main.xml LinearLayout I use a wallpaper...
However, everytime I want to scroll the list, it's always turns dark...

Later, I realize this because the listview is following the theme color...

What I want right now, is that when I scroll the list it won't follow the theme color
instead just be transparent to my wallpaper as my main.xml background...

Thanks!

Hope you guys can figured it out very soon....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got this problem: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html  Just use yourList.setCacheColorHint(0).